# Shell integer expression expected?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, error-handling

```
response=$(curl -sL -w \\n%{http_code} "http://<ip_addr>/api/1/app" -X DELETE)
echo response
if [ "$response" -eq 200 ]
then 
    echo "Got 200 OK"
else
    echo "not getting the result"
fi
```

- What i'm trying to do is to get the http response code.
- I'm positive that the response should be 200 OK
- When I run the script I'm getting

  ```
  {
      "result":true
  }
  200
  tst.sh: line 302: [: {
  200: integer expression expected
  ```
- I even don't want to display

  ```
  {
      "result":true
  }
  ```

  I just want to print 200 and compare 200.

Comment: I'm using bash shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just with curl command:

```
curl -sL -w '%{http_code}' "http://<ip_addr>/api/1/app" -X DELETE -o /dev/null
```

Comment: Just confirmed the idea. You got it first :)

Answer (score 2):

Get the last line of the output.

```
response=$(curl -sL -w \\n%{http_code} "http://<ip_addr>/api/1/app" -X DELETE | tail -1)
```

Besides `tail -n` you can also use:

```
awk 'END { print }'
sed -n '$p'
```

Another way if you're using bash is to remove everything before the last line:

```
shopt -s extglob
response=${response##*[[:space:]]}
```

Comment: @Adarsh [klashxx's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198894/445221) (`response=$(curl -sL -w '%{http_code}' "http://<ip_addr>/api/1/app" -X DELETE -o /dev/null)`) is better. I suggest you accept it instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your above, you are missing a `$` in your first echo, but no matter. You can strip the `{"result":true}` from the `$response` string

before the `if` statement:

`response=${response#*\}\ }`